# C++ - How to left/right circular shift a bitset?

Tags: c++, operators, c++20, bit-shift, bitset

Let's say I have a `std::bitset<28>` called `left28`.
I'm looking to [left circular shift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h3GK.png) `left28`.

[image: left circular shift illustration]

After doing some searching, I came across `std::rotl` (C++20) but it doesn't seem to play nice with `bitset`, so I have no idea how I'm going to pull this off.

Comment: You can use `operator<<` and `operator>>`.

Comment: Yes, but you can easily turn it into a circular one by adding one read and one write operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a **left circular shift** by combining right shifts with left shifts.

```
template<size_t N>
std::bitset<N> rotl( std::bitset<N> const& bits, unsigned count )
{
             count %= N;  // Limit count to range [0,N)
             return bits << count | bits >> (N - count);
// The shifted bits ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ The wrapped bits
}
```

Note that unlike `std::rotl`, the count in this example is `unsigned`.

If you would like it to be `signed`, like an `int`, write a matching `rotr` and have each function call the other when `count` is negative.

Comment: Extension to signed shift counts can be done by replacing the remainder operation with modulo.  Unfortunately C++ doesn't provide a standard modulo function.

Answer (score -1):

With 7 bits long number `b = 0b1011001`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
    int b, max;

    // highest 7 bits number.
    max     = 0b1111111;
    
    b       = 0b1011001;
    // left circular shifting.
    b = b << 1;
    while (b > max) {
        b -= max;
    }
    //---------------
    
    // Shows 0110011
    std::bitset<7> o(b);
    std::cout << o << " | " << b << std::endl;
}
```

And the right circular shifting is a left circular shifting at some point, so it would be something like:

```
b = b << 7 - 1;
while (b > max) {
    b -= max;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about `std::bitset`, and here the answer refers to  common `int`s.

Comment: Thanks for your note! it sure it is not an answer for the question, but it definitly does what the picture describing.

Comment: Yes, but for integer types, a fairly universal answer can be found in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/rotl, i.e. `(x << 1) | (x >> (N - 1) `.  Your answer lacks analysis why it works and how it deals with  the "signed/unsigned input" problem.